# Is this rifle, that can pivot 90° around corners, real?

Tags: realism, the-last-ship

I don't know if this is a rifle or SMG. [0:11](https://youtu.be/zUJU6lSn7CQ?t=11).

[image]

Comment: http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Last_Ship,_The

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

It's called a Cornershot:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CornerShot

> CornerShot is a weapon accessory invented by Lt. Col. Amos Golan of the Israeli Defense Forces in cooperation with American investors.[1] It was designed in the early 2000s for use by SWAT teams and special forces in hostile situations usually involving terrorists and hostages. Its purpose is similar to that of the periscope rifle; it allows its operator to both see and attack an
> armed target, without exposing the operator to counterattack.
>
> The standard CornerShot mounts a normal semi-automatic pistol in the front part of the weapon, with a remote linkage to the trigger mechanism in the rear part, it has a trigger pull of 21 newtons (4.7 lbf). It is 820 millimetres (32.67 in) long, with a weight of 3.86 kilograms (8.5 lb).